# Azure DevOps Pipeline stage filter issue

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Context:

I have two pipelines. Let's call them `trigger` and `trigger-two`.

`Trigger` pipeline has multiple stages, called `Troubleshooting`, `Troubleshooting2`, and `Troubleshooting3`.

My aim is to trigger `trigger-two` pipeline when the stages `Troubleshooting` and `Troubleshooting2` from `trigger` pipeline are completed.

Issue:

I have followed Microsoft documentation ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops ), but no matter how I implement it, the `trigger-two` pipeline is triggered only when the `trigger` pipeline is fully completed. The stage filter is not taken into consideration for unknown reasons.

Code for the `trigger-two` pipeline:

```
trigger: none

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: triggertest  
    source: triggertest
    project: project_name
    trigger:
      stages:
        - Troubleshooting
        - Troubleshooting2
      branches:
        include:
          - refs/heads/branchtest
```

Comment: check the docs it says the trigger will trigger the next pipeline after successful completion of the previous pipeline

Answer (score 3):

I tried to reproduce the issue, but it works in my pipeline.  Please try my my yaml：

pipeline `trigger`：

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

stages:
- stage: Troubleshooting1
  jobs:
  - job: Troubleshooting1
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          Write-Host "Hello World"
- stage: Troubleshooting2
  jobs:
  - job: Troubleshooting2
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          Write-Host "Hello World"
- stage: Troubleshooting3
  jobs:
  - job: Troubleshooting3
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          # Write your PowerShell commands here.
          Write-Host "Hello World" 
          #in order to add the time for this stage, install a Module 
          Install-Module Az -Scope CurrentUser -Force
```

Pipeline `trigger-two`：

```
trigger: none

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: trigger-resource  
    source: trigger
    project: testproject
    trigger:
      stages:
        - Troubleshooting1
        - Troubleshooting2
      branches:
        include:
          - refs/heads/main

pool: Default # Specify a self hosted agent pool by name. Because I only have one MS-hosted agent parallel job. So I use different pool in two yaml.
#pool:
#  vmImage: windows-latest
steps:
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      echo Write your commands here
      echo Hello world
```

[image]

Edit:

[image]

Comment: I have tested it now using the .yaml that you provided, and it still doesn't work.. the second pipeline is triggered only after the first one is completed.

Comment: I am testing now by adding `trigger: none` to the first pipeline too

Comment: Hi, I tested the above yaml in a new project/organization and the trigger-two pipeline is still triggered when the Troubleshooting2 stage is  finish.  Also, this time I only have one hosted agent when using vmImage: windows-latest, the  trigger-two pipeline is triggered and in the queue, but it will wait the stage Troubleshooting3 finish and then start to run on the same hosted agent.

Comment: I added a screenshot in the answer.